# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." При добавлении в список

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, исключения

Я пытаюсь реализовать добавление некоторого сигнала в список (Signals), внутри каждого signal другой список c данными (chunk). Вот код:

```
public static class DataGather
    {
        public class Sample : IComparable<Sample>
        {
            public string Time_ms;
            public string VarValue;
            public int CompareTo(Sample other)
            {
                // If other is not a valid object reference, this instance is greater.
                if (other == null) return 1;

                return Time_ms.CompareTo(other.Time_ms);
            }
        }

        public struct Chunk 
        {
            public List<Sample> samples;
        }

        public class Signal
        {
            public string VarName;
            public List<Chunk> chunks;
        }

        public static List<Signal> Signals = new List<Signal>();
```

При попытке добавить в элемент списка Signals данные "chunk" вызывается ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

chunk.samples было null.
Вот тестовый пример добавления данных в список "Signals"

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Signal signal = new Signal();
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
            Sample sample = new Sample();

            signal.VarName = "Signal1";
            Signals.Add(signal);

            foreach (var el in Signals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(el.VarName);
                int indexSignal = Array.IndexOf(Signals.ToArray(), el);
                sample.Time_ms = "10ms";
                sample.VarValue = "1";
                chunk.samples.Add(sample);
                Signals[indexSignal].chunks.Add(chunk);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Ошибка в этой строке, как исправить ошибку?:

```
chunk.samples.Add(sample);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш цикл вызывает недоумение, но допустим, что это тестовый код.

```
    public struct Chunk 
    {
        public List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
    }

    public class Signal
    {
        public string VarName;
        public List<Chunk> chunks = List<Chunk>();
    }
```

Comment: Да, это тестовый код

Comment: @ЧирковИлья В таком случае, знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.